# How to find the range of data on a MongoDB shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

When sharding a MongoDB collection using range partitioning and letting MongoDB handle balancing, how can I determine the range of data stored on each shard (without querying)?

For example, if partitioning on a string field that took values "A"-"Z", how could I find what letters are being stored on each node?

I need auto-balancing, so I cannot use zones/tagging either

Answer (score 0):

Check if [db.printShardingStatus()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.printShardingStatus/#db.printShardingStatus) or [sh.status()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.status/) help you in this regard. You can add **boolean** parameter to control **verbose** output which will display distribution of shard key across chunks.